# How to plot a decahedron with Mathematica?

Tags: graphics, polyhedra

I wrote

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.9], FaceForm[Yellow], PolyhedronData["Dipyramid", "Faces"]}]
```

and I get this picture:

[image: decahedron]

I would like to plot a decahedron without any defects on its surface. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `Graphics3D[{Opacity[1], FaceForm[Yellow], 
  PolyhedronData[{"Dipyramid", 5}, "Faces"]}]`

Comment: You're using a composite of all dipyramids, I think. Use `PolyhedronData[{"Dipyramid", 5}]`

Answer (score 2):

As said in my comment, you need to specify *which* you want, as in:

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[1], FaceForm[Yellow],    PolyhedronData[{"Dipyramid", 5}, "Faces"]}]
```

You can query for details of available incarnations with:

```
PolyhedronData["Dipyramid"]

(* {{"Dipyramid", 3}, {"Dipyramid", 5}, "Octahedron"} *)
```